# What type of files can be sent as inline in an email?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am currently fetching emails using pop3. I am trying to cover the ways in which an email can be present/sent. Images can be added as attachments as well as inline. Is there any other type of file that can be added as inline?

Comment: In theory you can send any attachment inline, it is then up to the mail client if it will honour that request to render it inline.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  Does any popular mail client allow to send a non image file inline?

Comment: You know it is a hint you can just ignore; an inline attachment is just an attachment that has an extra header with a hint for the client. If the client can't or doesn't want to follow that hint, it can just handle it as a normal attachment.

Comment: https://tdrive.li/JBHg9_pop3

In this case, I get the message content - one in rich text as text/html contenttype and one more in plain text as text/plain contenttype. But both will not have file names. In case if I add an image inline(using gmail), filename is present. I need to know if there are any other files that will not have file names but will be files ie not multipart/* or message/rfc822